# Wicket auto-generating <br> tags in inline links

Tags: html, tags, wicket, auto-generate

The code is as follows:

page_en.utf8.properties:

```
text=This is a ${testLink} link.
linkText=sample
```

page.java:

```
add(new BookmarkablePageLink<Void>("testLink");
```

page.html:

```
<div>
  <wicket:msg key="text">
    <a wicket:id="testLink" href="#">
      <wicket:msg key="linkText"></wicket:msg>
    </a>
  </wicket:msg>
</div>
```

output:

```
<div>
  This is a
  <a href="#">
   <br />
   sample
   <br />
  </a>
  link.
</div>
```

How can I remove the auto-generated br tags?

Comment: Please create a demo application and attach it to a ticket in Wicket's JIRA. I'd like to debug why this happens. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

`a[href="#"] > br{display: none;}`

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y8jp92sn/1/